# Wait for async forEach

Tags: vue.js

I need to stop my function myFunction() to process, if a zero value gets found in a jsonArray called this.constraint.costs.

this is my 1st function :

```
myFunction(){
  if(this.zeroValueCosts()){
      console.log(" Found an integer 0 value, I need to stop my function")
      return;
  };
}
```

this is my second supposed async function :

```
 async zeroValueCosts(){
        await this.constraint.costs.forEach(function(cost){
            if(cost.value = 0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

It doesn't work, no error displayed

What is the right way to use async/await with a forEach loop result ?

This is the this.constraints.costs array :

```
costs: [{
         "name": "new cost",
           "value": 0.06666
       },{
          "name": "new cost 2",
           "value": 0.05666
         }]
```

Comment: I think you need either `.map` or `.every` method, not `forEach`. `Array.forEach` method has not return value. And also you no need to use `async/await ` here.

Comment: Yep; `const res = constraint.costs.map(cost => cost.value !== 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you dont even need async await

```
async myFunction(){
  if(this.zeroValueCosts()){
      return;
  };
}

zeroValueCosts(){
   return constraint.costs.some(({ value }) => value === 0);
}
```

Comment: Actually, he does not even need the `async` modifier - as none of the shown code is asynchronous.

Comment: @IVOGELOV yea, forgott to remove it

Comment: @harmoniuscool is your value 0.066666 maybe an string and not an integer?

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: Not it is an integer, I have checked it using typeof()

Comment: @harmoniuscool i have edited my post